# How to reduce same strings in a 'foreach'?

Tags: c#, string

I'm new programming an have this issue that I couldn't get what i want to do, this is my code

```
foreach(RunePage rune in runePages)
{
    if(rune.Slots != null && rune.Slots.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(RuneSlot runeSlot in rune.Slots)
        {
            var runeName = staticApi.GetRune(RiotSharp.Region.lan, runeSlot.RuneId,    RuneData.tags, Language.es_ES).Name;
            richTextBox1.Text = runeName + "\n" + richTextBox1.Text;
        }
     }
     richTextBox1.Text = rune.Name + "\n" + richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

Output:

> AP
>
> Greater Quintessence of Ability Power
>
> Greater Quintessence of Ability Power
>
> Greater Quintessence of Ability Power
>
> Greater Glyph of Ability Power
>
> Greater Glyph of Magic Resist
>
> Greater Glyph of Ability Power
>
> Greater Glyph of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Glyph of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Glyph of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Glyph of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Glyph of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Glyph of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Seal of Ability Power
>
> Greater Seal of Ability Power
>
> Greater Seal of Ability Power
>
> Greater Seal of Armor
>
> Greater Seal of Armor
>
> Greater Seal of Armor
>
> Greater Seal of Armor
>
> Greater Seal of Armor
>
> Greater Seal of Armor
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration
>
> Greater Mark of Magic Penetration

and all I want is something like this Output

> AP
>
> 3x Greater Quintessence of Ability Power
>
> 2x Greater Glyph of Ability Power
>
> 1x Greater Glyph of Magic Resist
>
> 6x Greater Glyph of Magic Penetration
>
> 3x Greater Seal of Ability Power
>
> 6x Greater Seal of Armor
>
> 9x Greater Mark of Magic Penetration

How do I do this?

Comment: Use a map or other collection type to keep a count of each string, with the string value as the key.

Comment: Is that the output from one page, or from the whole thing? It's not clear what your input data is... LINQ will almost certainly help you though.

Comment: Well this is different, I wasn't expecting a question which encompasses League of Legends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of LINQ you could use a simple dictionary, something like this:

```
var runeTotals = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(RuneSlot runeSlot in rune.Slots)
{
    var runeName = staticApi.GetRune(RiotSharp.Region.lan, runeSlot.RuneId, RuneData.tags, Language.es_ES).Name;
    if (runeTotals.ContainsKey(runeName))
    {
        runeTotals[runeName] += 1;
        continue;
    }
    runeTotals.Add(runeName, 1);
}

foreach (var runeTotal in runeTotals)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = runeTotal.Value + "x " + runeTotal.Key + "\n" + richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

If items are listed more that they are changed, you could keep the dictionary global and update it when an item is added or removed.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using LINQ to group and count them:

```
// TODO: Build up the whole string, and set the Text property once.
// Oh, and rename richTextBox1 to something more descriptive.
foreach (RunePage rune in runePages)
{
    if (rune.Slots != null)
    {
        var grouped = rune.Slots
             .GroupBy(slot => slot.RuneId)
             .Select(group => new { Name = staticApi.GetRune(RiotSharp.Region.lan, 
                                                             group.Key, RuneData.tags, 
                                                             Language.es_ES).Name),
                                    Count = group.Count() })
             .Select(pair => string.Format("{0}x {1}", pair.Count, pair.Name));
        richTextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", grouped);
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = rune.Name + "\n" + richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx). It may look complex if you never worked with it, but it is simpler than using more classical approach with dictionaries and manual reduce.

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetRuneStrings()
{
    foreach(RunePage rune in runePages)
    {
        if(rune.Slots != null && rune.Slots.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(RuneSlot runeSlot in rune.Slots)
            {
                var runeName = staticApi.GetRune(RiotSharp.Region.lan, runeSlot.RuneId,    RuneData.tags, Language.es_ES).Name;             
                yield return runeName;
            }
         }
         yield return rune.Name;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<String> GetAggregatedRuneStrings()
{
    return GetRuneStrings().
        GroupBy(runeStr => runeStr).
        Select(runeStrGroup => String.Format("{0} x {1}", runeStrGroup.First(), runStrGroup.Count()));
}


public void AddRuneStringsToRichTextBox()
{
    richTextBox1.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetAggregatedRuneStrings().ToArray());
}
```